# Is there a more pythonic way of exploding a list over a function's arguments?

Tags: python, list, function, parameters, arguments

```
def foo(a, b, c):
 print a+b+c

i = [1,2,3]
```

Is there a way to call foo(i) without explicit indexing on i?
Trying to avoid foo(i[0], i[1], i[2])

Comment: Used in function definition many times, so why not use it when calling... Thanks for reverting my python head guys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use [`foo(*i)`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> foo(*i)
6
```

You can also use `*` in function definition:
`def foo(*vargs)` puts all non-keyword arguments into a tuple called `vargs`.
and the use of `**`, for eg., `def foo(**kargs)`, will put all keyword arguments into a dictionary called `kargs`:

```
>>> def foo(*vargs, **kargs):
        print vargs
        print kargs

>>> foo(1, 2, 3, a="A", b="B")
(1, 2, 3)
{'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's called [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and there's an operator for it.

```
foo(*i)
```

By the way, it works with any iterable, not just with lists.

Comment: +1 for dropping the name of the game. actually this what helps to google this thing for any language. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Python supports that:

```
foo(*i)
```

See the documentation on [Unpacking Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). Works with anything iterable. With two stars `**` it works for dicts and named arguments.

```
def bar(a, b, c): 
    return a * b * c
j = {'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 2}

bar(**j)
```